# Remove all thumbnails generated with easy-thumbnails Django App

Tags: django, thumbnails, easy-thumbnails

I am using [easy-thumbnails](https://github.com/SmileyChris/easy-thumbnails) in my Django 1.5 project to generate thumbnail images.

I have been using several different sizes for thumbnails for testing, but now I would like to clear all thumbnails from my filesystem and from the easy-thumbnails database entries. Over time I created several different sizes of many images and I would like to remove those now.

My intention is to start with a clean slate and to remove all thumbnail images. I could not find out how to do that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just had the same problem.

Given:

```
class MyModel(Model):
    image = ThumbnailerImageField()
```

You can delete all thumbnails with:

```
for m in MyModel.objects.all():
    m.image.delete_thumbnails()
```

If you instead have:

```
class MyModel(Model):
    image = ImageField()
```

Then you should use:

```
from easy_thumbnails.files import get_thumbnailer

for m in MyModel.objects.all():
    thumbnailer = get_thumbnailer(m.image)
    thumbnailer.delete_thumbnails()
```

Comment: works for me, but import should be:

`from easy_thumbnails.files import get_thumbnailer`

(missing s in easy_thumbnails in the code above)

Comment: Hey guys. Actually, this solution does not work for me. Is it correct now?

Answer (score 6):

I have created a Picture model in which I added a method, as follows

```
from easy_thumbnails.models import Source, Thumbnail
def clean_thumbnail(self):
    if self.image:
        sources = Source.objects.filter(name=self.image.name)
        if sources.exists():
            for thumb in Thumbnail.objects.filter(source=sources[0]):
                try:
                    os.remove(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, thumb.name))
                    thumb.delete()
                except Exception, e:
                    logger.warning(e)
```

And it works like a charm.

Comment: Could have used `thumbnail_default_storage` to delete the file.